# Generate a complete bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using BibTeX to make a list of references without having citations in the body of the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17128/using-bibtex-to-make-a-list-of-references-without-having-citations-in-the-body-of)

Is there an easy way, given a bibtex file, to generate a compiled version of the entire bibliography?

I could create a minimal document with a bunch of `\nocite{}` commands, but that would require me to update it each time I add a reference to the bibliography.

Comment: If you came here to ask whether/how you can generate a full “fake” bibliography, I've asked a new question for that: [How to generate a example/lorem ipsum bibliography in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/549658/98645)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Does `\nocite{*}` solve your problem?