# How to print, with biblatex, the bibliography with the whole content of my bib-file?

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to fine-tune the biblatex output. To test the result, I would like to see how it works for all entries in my bib-file. Is it possible to achieve this without copying all keys manually?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6885/generate-a-complete-bibliography

Comment: Since this question specifically asks about biblatex, I'm not sure if it can be considered a duplicate.

Comment: @Caramdir But the solution is the same, so this is independent of biblatex.

Comment: @Alan: But obviously it wasn't findable using Google, which indicates that we should have a separate question about it. Biblatex can, after all, be sometimes quite different. Also see locksteps comment to the answer.

Comment: @Alan: The question suggests the OP might want the 'debug' style in `biblatex` in addition to the more general 'cite everything' situation

Comment: Ok. I'm convinced.  (Although someone might want to add a `biblatex` answer in that case.) Is there a way to un-vote to close?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
\nocite{*}
```

should be what you are looking for. It prints all of your entries, including the uncited ones into your bibliography. You enter it somewhere between `\begin{document} ... \end{document}`

I'm including locksteps comment into the answer:

> With biblatex, you can also write
>   `\nocite{*}` in the preamble.

Comment: With biblatex, you can also write `\nocite{*}` in the preamble.

Comment: @texnic: If the answer was helpful to you, you could accept it when you're sure no better answer comes along. :-) Also, if you haven't already, you could upvote locksteps comment. In my opinion it really enhances the answer!! :-)

Comment: Thanks. BTW, it is possible to use code samples inside blockquotes.

Comment: I would vote up the lockstep's comment and also that old an_ant's answer but I don't yet have enough privilege for it :) 

Guys, thanks very much for help. It's really stupid I couldn't find \nocite{*} myself, but somehow I spent about an hour with biblatex.pdf, Google and Stackexchange but failed to find what I needed.