# Using BibTeX/biblatex to make a list of references without having citations in the body of the document?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, citing

Is there any way to have BibTeX or `biblatex` insert a bibliography without having citations in the body of the document itself? Maybe a way to hide the in-text citations, so that BibTeX still sees them and includes them in the bibliography, but does not print them in the body?

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Use `\nocite{*}` in the body of your document to include all the references in the .bib database. To include only some bibliographical entries, you can use `\nocite{key1,key2,...,keyn}` to include only the entries corresponding to `key1,key2,...,keyn`.

Comment: Ah, I actually hadn't realized that the exact command \nocite{*} worked -- I took * as a wildcard standing in for the citation name i wanted to include -- I added a \nocite{} for each reference I wanted, worked great!

Comment: @Alan Munn: I've edited my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: I'm using biblatex package and I' adding author names to author index using this `\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
\usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[cite]}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}`. What should I do if I want to add authors to author index with `\nocite` macro? I could catch...

Comment: Does `\nocite{*}` work using `BibTeX`? It doesn't work for me. If not, is there a similar command for `BibTeX`?

Comment: I did put \nocite{*} but it doesnt work for me...

Answer (score 3):

Using the `apacite` package, the following code works for me:

```
\usepackage{url} % Link bibliography links (avoid long links for clarity)
\usepackage{breakurl} % Break URLs over multiple lines
\usepackage{hyperref} % Link bibliography links (avoid long links for clarity)
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document} 
    \bibliography{ref/lib} % References a "lib.bib" file inside of the "ref" folder
    \bibliographystyle{apacite}
    \nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hrmmm, at the core of the answer is the `\nocite{*}` which is already discussed in the other answer. Apart from that I can't see the need to load `etoolbox` in this particular example. You also have `\bibliographystyle` twice (which is probably not an error on the LaTeX side, but BibTeX doesn't like that). Plus `natbib` and `apacite` should ideally not be used together like this (they can be used together, but then that should be done with `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}`). ...

Comment: ...  `\usepackage{breakurl}` is not recommendable with all toolchains (I'd say it's only useful in a minority of cases). Generally it is recommended to load `hyperref` last (subject to a few documented exceptions; I'm not aware that `natbib` is such an exception).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!