# How to list all bibliography entries without citing

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I've read that "All items listed in the bibliography should be cited in the body of the paper."

But if I did not cite any item in the `.tex` file, how can I list the items in the bibliography? That's it, I did not want to cite any item, but to appear in the bibliography section

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17128/using-bibtex-to-make-a-list-of-references-without-having-citations-in-the-body-of) question.

Comment: Your question created an unregistered account which I merged with your existing one. Please consider to fully register that account to avoid this in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 184):

write `\nocite{*}` for *all* entries in the used bib data file or `\nocite{<key>}` for a single one, which is not cited in the text. Place these commands anywhere in your text body. I prefer the place before printing the bib.

Comment: I have done so, but when i run the file, nothing gets printed in the references.