# How can I add bibliography references which are not cited?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using BibTeX to make a list of references without having citations in the body of the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17128/using-bibtex-to-make-a-list-of-references-without-having-citations-in-the-body-of)

I have a simple question about adding references in a document. Is it possible to add references in LaTeX that is not cited in the document? If it is, how can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\nocite{<key>}
```

or for all from the database

```
\nocite{*}
```