# Reference list only shows titles which are referenced in the thesis

Tags: bibliographies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using BibTeX to make a list of references without having citations in the body of the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17128/using-bibtex-to-make-a-list-of-references-without-having-citations-in-the-body-o)

I would like to publish all titles in the reference list, including those which are not cited in the paper. How can I do so with "apacite"?

Comment: The command you are looking for is `\nocite{}` and it is described in the question @MarcoDaniel linked to. Or you could of course [search this site for nocite](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=nocite)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. If the question referenced to by Marco Daniel doesn't help you, please expand your question. Otherwise this one will be closed so as to keep the site more easily accessible.