# a bibliography with uncited references

Tags: natbib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using BibTeX to make a list of references without having citations in the body of the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17128/using-bibtex-to-make-a-list-of-references-without-having-citations-in-the-body-o)

I'd like some specific entries to appear in my bibliography that I don't intend to cite (i.e. it's a first year report and I just have to show that I'm reading widely).  How would you go about adding multiple entries to your natbib (preferably) managed referenced.

The best I can think of is putting them in something like `\phantom`, but then I'll end up with lots of white-space

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17128/using-bibtex-to-make-a-list-of-references-without-having-citations-in-the-body-o. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: yes `\nocite` is what I was after; not sure why I didn't see it before...  very embarrassing!