# Generate .tex output from .bib file to cut and paste

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have a paper (written in Sci Word, but I think that's irrelevant) and I would like to format the bibliography to match a journal's style guide. The authors did the references manually, so I need to generate a bibliography in tex that I can just cut-and-paste into the references section.

It seems the easiest way is to generate my own .bib file with the references and somehow trick bibtex into giving the tex output that I can save to a text file (the authors don't want me to link the references with `\cite{}`s or edit the body of the paper).

Is this possible? Or are the only solutions at the extremes (i.e., doing the `\cite{}`s or completely manually generating the bibliography)? Thanks!

Comment: `\nocite{*}` will cause all the items in the `.bib` file to be included in the `.bbl` file, which you can then cut and paste. actually, this has been covered before in [Using BibTeX to make a list of references without having citations in the body of the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17128/)

Comment: Ah, OK. I think this is much better. :) They should be OK with this approach. Thanks! I will close as a duplicate.