# How do I print out more than 200 citations in \begin{thebibliography} ... \end{thebibliography}

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I have more than 200 citations in a simple

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{stuff}Citation ......
\bibitem{ etc ....
200 times
\end{thebibliography}
```

when I compile it, it won't give me all of the citations. Any ideas? I can't put the citations into BibTeX format. I am constrained by time.

Comment: Does a `\nocite{*}` help?

Comment: Not to answer your question, but for 200+ citations you'll need `\begin{thebibliography}{999}...\end{thebibliography}`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Using BibTeX to make a list of references without having citations in the body of the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128/5764)

Comment: Have you checked the log file for any error messages or warnings?

Comment: @Tobi With a hand made bibliography section all the citations will be printed regardless of whether they are cited in the main document or not, so `\nocite` is not necessary.

Comment: why the close votes saying it's a duplicate of a bibtex question?

Comment: I'm inclined to think a closing brace is missing somewhere.

Comment: Hi **tmwitten** and welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. As to your question, I second @egreg 's comment: There's quite likely a mistake in the code somewhere. Try to shorten it by saying '\end{thebibliography}\end{document}` at different points of your bibliography, and this way to find from what moment you get into troubles. Then edit your question and update it with what you find this way.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: Thanks, I wasn’t sure about this (using `biblatex` normally) an thought it could be a quick fix …