# Existing solution for biblatex

Tags: biblatex

@daniel I did run `biber` and it does not show any mismatch in version @moewe. Here is the result.

[image]

Result of `\listfiles`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,includefoot,asymmetric]{geometry}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\newpage
%input "XBib.bib"
%\setlinespacing{1.44}
%\bibliographystyle{chicago}.
\printbibliography
%\bibliography{XBib}
\end{document}
```

BIBLIOGRAPHY FILE

```
@article{glashow,
  author       = {Glashow, Sheldon},
  title        = {Partial Symmetries of Weak Interactions},
  journaltitle = {Nucl.~Phys.},
  date         = 1961,
  volume       = 22,
  pages        = {579-588},
}
```

Comment: Usually your `.blg` ([`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) `.log` file) should end with `INFO - Writing 'thesis.bbl` with encoding XXX`, which I don't see here. This may be due to your warning. You should update to a more recent version of [`biber`](http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/) and [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)...

Comment: See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1)

Comment: updated miktex packages but problem still persists. any thing else shall i check?

Comment: If you still get the same warning that you didn't updated your miktex correctly. If you have a multiuser installation You need to run the update manager in user and admin mode.

Comment: Side note: Please paste log files etc. here as plain text so that other users with the same problem stand a chance of finding this question.

Comment: biber is updated to version 1.8 but still i m getting the same warnings

Comment: @user42754 Can you cook up a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/)? Does the problem persist if you try to compile a different document?

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,includefoot,asymmetric]{geometry}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
%input "XBib.bib"
%\setlinespacing{1.44}
%\bibliographystyle{chicago}.
\printbibliography
%\bibliography{XBib}
\end{document}

Comment: % BIBLIOGRAPHY FILE
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
@article{glashow,
  author       = {Glashow, Sheldon},
  title        = {Partial Symmetries of Weak Interactions},
  journaltitle = {Nucl.~Phys.},
  date         = 1961,
  volume       = 22,
  pages        = {579-588},
}

Comment: but \parencite{} shows reference key instead of reference cited

Comment: and yes the problem persists if i compile another document.

Comment: @user42754 You can [edit] your question to add code and information.

Comment: @moewe I am curious, is that you? ;-) http://golatex.de/viewtopic,p,72143.html#72143

Answer (score 3):

Your example has some lacks:

- There is no `\begin{document}`
- You didn't load the external file which is normally done by `\addbibresource{ <filename>.bib}`
- You need either to cite the relevant entry or use `\nocite{}` as explained here: [Using BibTeX to make a list of references without having citations in the body of the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17128/using-bibtex-to-make-a-list-of-references-without-having-citations-in-the-body-o)

Based on this information here an example which should work on your machine ( I also removed not needed packages:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@article{glashow,
  author       = {Glashow, Sheldon},
  title        = {Partial Symmetries of Weak Interactions},
  journaltitle = {Nucl.~Phys.},
  date         = 1961,
  volume       = 22,
  pages        = {579-588},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{glashow}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The result is:

> [image]

Comment: @Daniel thanks a lot... but my machine has stuck there. its giving warning of empty bibliography and undefined citation. do i need to re install?

Comment: seems biblatex is not identifying bib file

Comment: Do you really have an updated system? Please use \listfiles` inside the example above and show us the output of `\listfiles` by editing your original question. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13304/which-package-version-am-i-using/13305#13305

Comment: i do not understand what is the problem?

Comment: @user42754: based on the information above it seems you are missing to run biber.

Comment: @user42754 You need to at least run `latex`, `biber`, `latex`, `latex` on the test document above. Does the `biber` run still warn about expecting a different version of the control file?

Comment: it also shows no file test.bbl

Comment: views on some web pages are to delete par cache but i can not find the location of that either

Comment: data source C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\par-5061756ccache-890efc00b3ca6b775c7d44a325c1349fb2a3a3bd\inc\lib/Biber/LaTeX/recode_data.xml not found in .but i could not find any folder named AppData in C\Users\username

Comment: thanks all i have tried these solution its working on other machines which was'nt working before.

Comment: @user42754: Your error is a known issue. Just removed the file pointing in the error message.

Comment: @ Daniel the problem is i could find that file in the specified path.

Comment: @Daniel i removed that folder but i think error lies before that as in running latex it indicates no bcf.