# Is there a way to just compile contents of a .bib file?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, chicago-style

Probably a complete newbie question. When writing with LaTeX I have no problem with my bibliography but of course it only compiles entries that I have cited in my document. I would have all my readings in the .bib file even if they have not being cited yet.

I am wondering if there is a way to produce with LaTeX just the contents of the .bib file?

PS. Not sure what extra info I may need to give. Don't think I can give a MWE as don't know how to recreate issue. I use TeXstudio on Ubuntu 14.04 and use the following as my bibliography settings.

```
\usepackage[notes, backend=biber, bookpages=false]{biblatex-chicago}
```

If any other info is needed please leave a comment.

Comment: add `\nocite{*}` somewhere in your document

Comment: David is right (as always). See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128/15925