# referencing non-cited sources

Tags: bibliographies, citing, jabref

I created a bibliography library .bib-file with JabRef. Some sources are cited in the text and the bibliography entry in the end is automatically added - very nice. But how can I add sources that are not cited in the text in the same bibliography style as the cited ones? With \bibitem{keyword} they are numbered and do not appear in the same style.

Moreover, for some sources not all required information is given. How can I make the bibliography entry look the same as the complete ones, but just with some information missing?

Comment: For the first part, I'm sure this question already has an answer somewhere, but I couldn't find it right now. But try ``\nocite{Bibtex-Key}``, this should put the reference into your bibliography without having it as a citation. For the second question, I guess we will need a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to be able to help you.

Comment: Duplicate of the first part of your question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128/18674. Maybe you want to remove that part and elaborate a bit more on the second question.

Comment: These are very useful answers. concerning the second question, I will try to make the incomplete sources look equal among each other, while they mey appear not equal to the properly referenced (complete) sources.

Comment: You can edit your question to add such information and *please* try to create a MWE that shows what you have and that you can use to explain what you need. As it stands, at least I cannot imagine, what exactly is your problem.

Comment: Did the answer to the duplicate of the first part work? That is, did `\nocite{*}` or `\nocite{bibkey}` work? For the second, I'm with @BenediktBauer: without an MWE, it is anybody's guess what you are asking. Generally speaking, the software will try to format things sensibly even if some information is missing from the bib entries. However, especially if you are using `bibtex` rather than `biblatex`, sometimes you need to help a bit by massaging the entries.

Comment: Are there any news here?

Comment: it worked. The problem was the right settings for the compilation (bibtex/biblatex)