# Bibliography - Only the cited items appear

Tags: bibliographies

I have written a text and I included the bibliography.

I have cited only two of the items of the bibliography and now only these two appear in the bibliography. Why?

I used the following comands:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{mybibliography}
```

For the bibliography I created a .bib file.

---

When I use

```
\bibliographystyle{alpha} 
\bibliography{mybibliography}
```

some of the errors I get are the following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What do these errors mean?

Comment: That is the advantage of automatic bib creation, only the things you explicitely cite are added. If you want all, use `\nocite{*}`.

Comment: Normally only those items of the `.bib` that are actually cited appear in the bibliography. If you want to see all of the entries, issue `\nocite{*}` if you want to force only some entries to appear in the bibliography even though they were not cited use `\nocite{foo}`.

Comment: See [Using BibTeX to make a list of references without having citations in the body of the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128/35864)

Comment: Ok... I used now `\nocite{*}` and all the items appear... I have also an other problem... When I use `\bibliographystyle{alpha}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{plain}` I get some errors... I will add the errors I get at my question above... @moewe

Comment: Could you take a look at my question above? I added some errors I get... @Johannes_B

Comment: Mary, you know the drill. Post a minimal working example and the log file that generates the shown errors, this is possible with sharelatex, i know it, it done it. Without it, we are just as confused as the sharelatex compiler.

Comment: Sorry, as Johannes_B says, we really need to see an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), that is real code, not just a screen shot of the errors in your favourite online compiler. But this `\fo` looks a bit suspicious, does it appear in anything you have control over?

Comment: I will post a minimal working example... This `\fo` maybe comes from `\foreignlanguage{english}{...}`. @moewe

Comment: It is definitely not a good idea to wrap the `author` names in `\foreignlanguage{english}{...}`.

Comment: Also, a new question should be a new question and should have a new headline.  Otherwise people get confused why this very simple question still has no answer.