# How can I manually add bib entries?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have a `.bib` file so that every work cited with a `\cite*` command appears in the bibliography. But how do I add an extra item which I don't `\cite` anywhere in the document?

I am looking for a command like `\addbibentry{author1999}`, but have not found anything.

Comment: good answer here: [Using BibTeX to make a list of references without having citations in the body of the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\nocite`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
abc \nocite{Andrews99}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

test.bib:

```
@book{Andrews99,
author   = {Andrews, G. E. and Askey, R. and Roy, R.},
title    = {Special Functions},
publisher= {Cambridge University Press},
year     = {1999}
}
```

[image: nocite]