# BibLaTeX - only 3 references possible

Tags: biblatex

I'm using a template with BibLaTeX for the bibliography, currently I'm only able to make 3 references appear on the write up at any one time. Please could someone advise me as to why this is and how I can enable more to appear.

Here is my code:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} 

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

@booklet{Reference1,
    Author = {B.Cook},
    Title = {An alternative Model of Cosmology},
    Year = {2010}}

@book{Reference2,
    Author = {P.Coles},
    Title = {Cosmology: A very short introduction},
    Publisher = {UOP Oxford},
    Year = {2001}}

@book{Reference3,
    Author = {V.H.Ironside},
    Title = {Behold! I Teach You Superman},
    Publisher = {Malleus Maleficus},
    Year = {2010}}

@mastersthesis{Reference4,
    Author = {S.Bhargava},
    Title = {Type Ia Supernovae and Testing   Inhomogenious Models of Cosmology},
    School = {University College London},
    Year = {2016}}

\end{thebibliography}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

Only the top 3 references are showing.

Comment: http://tex.my/how-to-ask-for-latex-related-help-effectively/

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It's impossible to help you without more informtion about what you are doing: please give full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. Cutting your code down to a MWE may well reveal what your problem actually is.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). ||| Have a look at what is a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407), it will help us help you!

Comment: Are you citing the 4th reference?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you should separate with a space the initial and the family name in the `author` field. And you should *not* use the `thebibliography` environment for that data. It should be in an external file.

Comment: Thank you all! All sorted, I didn't realise each reference needed to be cited before appearing.

Comment: @JulianLawford you can use `\nocite{*}` if you want everything in the bib file to be in the bibliography.

Comment: So this is essentially a duplicate of [Using BibTeX to make a list of references without having citations in the body of the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128/35864)

Comment: @moewe Yes, it's the same but with BibLaTeX instead of BibTeX

Comment: @CarLaTeX Well that hardly matters, I'd think. But I'd like the OP to confirm that he thinks it is a duplicate as well before I vote to close.

Comment: @moewe the MWE seems to have other issues (e.g., I don't think `biblatex/biber` works with the `thebibliography` environment). This does not seem like one of those "good" duplicates.

Comment: @StrongBad Well you can hardly call the code here an MWE (maybe some of the wrong code was only introduced in the process of trying to make an MWE), that is why I asked for the OP's opinion about this (he stated the problem is solved by citing/`\nocite`ing the relevant references after all) instead of closing right away as a 'good' duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I prepared a MWE with your rar given informations.

Please see the following code:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@booklet{Reference1,
  Author = {B. Cook},
  Title  = {An alternative Model of Cosmology},
  Year   = {2010},
}
@book{Reference2,
  Author = {P. Coles},
  Title = {Cosmology: A very short introduction},
  Publisher = {UOP Oxford},
  Year = {2001},
}
@book{Reference3,
    Author = {V.H. Ironside},
    Title = {Behold! I Teach You Superman},
    Publisher = {Malleus Maleficus},
    Year = {2010},
}
@mastersthesis{Reference4,
    Author = {S. Bhargava},
    Title = {Type Ia Supernovae and Testing   Inhomogenious Models of Cosmology},
    School = {University College London},
    Year = {2016},
}
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
    keywords =     "physics",
}
@book{dirac,
    title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn={9780198520115},
    series={International series of monographs on physics},
    year={1981},
    publisher={Clarendon Press},
    keywords = {physics},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear,
  natbib=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Some \autocite{Reference4} text \cite{Reference4}.

\nocite{*} % <========== to call all uncited bib entrys to be added to bibliography
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

To get a proper sorting you need to divide firstnames and lastnames of authors with an blank. I added that to your given bib entrys. See for example:

```
@booklet{Reference1,
  Author = {B. Cook},
%             ^ added blank!
  Title  = {An alternative Model of Cosmology},
  Year   = {2010},
}
```

The environment `thebibliography` is created by `biblatex` and `biber` in the resulting `bbl` file, do not use it by your own in your code.

Command `\nocites{*}` adds *all* uncited bib entrys to the printed bibliography and that is that what you want and need ...

Package `filecontents` is only used here to have BiB file and TeX code concatenated into one compiling MWE. Please do not use it in your real code!

With my given MWE you get after compiling with `pdflatex`, `biber`,`pdflatex` and `pdflatex` the following result:

[image]