# Can't Use Bib File

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, errors, compiling

[So I am new to LaTex. I am self taught, so I apologize ahead of time if I am difficult to work with.]

I am trying to write a paper for a class, and I'd like to cite my sources using a bib file. I am able to do the basics, but for some reason my TeX studio will not compile my document. It appears to stop near the top, at the " \begin{document}" line, and I cannot figure out why. Here is what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex,
    style=alphabetic,
    sorting=nyt,
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{wage.bib}
\title{title}
\author{name}
\date{date}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
```

... [content]

```
\printbibliography[title=Works Cited]

\end{document}
```

I keep getting an error that says "! File ended while scanning use of \field", with the "begin document" line highlighted in red. Here is my bib file:

```
@article{poverty,
author =       "John Addison and Mickinley Blackburn",
title =        "Minimum Wages and Poverty",
journal =      "Industrial Labor Relations Review",
volume =       "52",
number =       "3",
pages =        "891--921",
year =         "1999",
}

@article{realwage,
author =       "Orley Ashenfelter",
title =        "Comparing Real Wage Rates",
journal =      "American Economic Association",
volume =       "102",
number =       "2",
pages =        "891--921",
year =         "2012",
}

@article{hours,
author =       "Kenneth Couch and David Wittenburg",
title =        "The Resposne of Hours of Work to Increase in the Minimum Wage",
journal =      "Southern Economic Journal",
volume =       "68",
number =       "1",
pages =        "891--921",
year =         "2001",
}

@article{profits,
author =       "Mirko Draca and Stephen Machin and John Van Reenen",
title =        "Minimum Wages and Firm Profitability",
journal =      "American Economic Association",
volume =       "3",
number =       "1",
pages =        "891--921",
year =         "2011",
}

@article{ninefity,
author =       "Joseph Sabia and RIchard Burkenhauser",
title =        "Minimum Wages and Poverty: Will a 9.50 Federal Minimum IWage Really Help the Working Poor?",
journal =      "Southern Economic Journal",
volume =       "76",
number =       "3",
pages =        "891--921",
year =         "2010",
}

@article{politics,
author =       "Russell Sobel",
title =        "Theory and Evidence on the Political Economy of the Minimum Wage",
journal =      "Journal of Political Economy",
volume =       "107",
number =       "4",
pages =        "891--921",
year =         "1999",
}
```

It was not too long ago when I was able to compile this document just fine. This trouble started when I copy and pasted some sources (in fact, the last two sources of my bib file) into the bib file. I discovered that they had the braces on, instead of the quotations. But after correcting this my document still won't print. This is very frustrating. I've plaid around with the biber / bibtex option, to no avail ; I have read somewhere that I need to change the compiling order under Options - Configure TeX - Build - Default Compiler, but I do not quite understand what this option is, nor does it appear to be doing much.

In addition, when I had a bibliography, I noticed that the bibliography would only print the things I cited within the paper, instead of all of the sources actually listed in my bib file. This was also frustrating.

To summarize, I just want to print/compile this document, with all of the sources in my bib file appearing, in alphabetical order. The contents of the paper is already prepared, it is just the compiling that I am having issue with.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! Try deleting all generated files and recompiling. You need to make sure that your editor uses `biber` if you specify that backend or `bibtex` if you specify that one. Braces work fine in `.bib` files. I only ever use braces. I call them curly brackets, but that's just me.

Comment: Aren't most people who use LaTeX self-taught?

Comment: Note that the entry `ninefity` contains at least two small typos. See also [Using BibTeX to make a list of references without having citations in the body of the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128/35864). The `\field` error is not something we can replicate with the code you have given. Either it is not present any more and can be gotten rid of by deleting temporary (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`) files and recompiling, or it lies with other `.bib` entries we can't see. Note that braces instead of quotation marks are valid, if done right.

Comment: If you are previewing your PDF in an External PDF reader that can prevent TexStudio from compiling. In that case shut down the external reader and recompile from TexStudio.

Answer (score 3):

By default, only cited sources are included. If you wish to include everything add

```
\nocite{*}
```

somewhere.

You may need to remove generated files to get past the error. Delete the `.bbl`, `.blg`, `.bcf` and/or `.aux` file and try recompiling. You do need to ensure that your editor uses the correct backend i.e. if you specify `biber` (or nothing), it needs to use `biber`; if you specify `bibtex`, it needs to use `bibtex`.

Here's my version of your code, with all sources included.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{poverty,
author =       "John Addison and Mickinley Blackburn",
title =        "Minimum Wages and Poverty",
journal =      "Industrial Labor Relations Review",
volume =       "52",
number =       "3",
pages =        "891--921",
year =         "1999",
}

@article{realwage,
author =       "Orley Ashenfelter",
title =        "Comparing Real Wage Rates",
journal =      "American Economic Association",
volume =       "102",
number =       "2",
pages =        "891--921",
year =         "2012",
}

@article{hours,
author =       "Kenneth Couch and David Wittenburg",
title =        "The Resposne of Hours of Work to Increase in the Minimum Wage",
journal =      "Southern Economic Journal",
volume =       "68",
number =       "1",
pages =        "891--921",
year =         "2001",
}

@article{profits,
author =       "Mirko Draca and Stephen Machin and John Van Reenen",
title =        "Minimum Wages and Firm Profitability",
journal =      "American Economic Association",
volume =       "3",
number =       "1",
pages =        "891--921",
year =         "2011",
}

@article{ninefity,
author =       "Joseph Sabia and RIchard Burkenhauser",
title =        "Minimum Wages and Poverty: Will a 9.50 Federal Minimum IWage Really Help the Working Poor?",
journal =      "Southern Economic Journal",
volume =       "76",
number =       "3",
pages =        "891--921",
year =         "2010",
}

@article{politics,
author =       "Russell Sobel",
title =        "Theory and Evidence on the Political Economy of the Minimum Wage",
journal =      "Journal of Political Economy",
volume =       "107",
number =       "4",
pages =        "891--921",
year =         "1999",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
    backend=bibtex,
    style=alphabetic,
    sorting=nyt,
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\title{title}
\author{name}
\date{date}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[title=Works Cited]

\end{document}
```

[image: output with all sources]

`biber` is recommended over `bibtex`, though, so I'd suggest changing `backend=bibtex` to `backend=biber`.

This produces a similar result:

[image: Biber as backend]

Comment: cfr wrote "You may need to remove generated files to get past the error". A tip for the OP, in TexStudio this can be done with the command `Tools > Clean Auxiliary Files ...`. The shortcut is F2. But it's a good idea to keep a manual eye on the effect this has (e.g. through your OS's File Manager).