# How to compile reference list not directly used in the latex file

Tags: bibtex

I just figured that the reference list are not compiled unless I directly cite them on latex file. Is this the norms?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I guess you want to be more specific. There are many different ways of adding references (by hand, bibtex, biber,...) and the answer will depend on the specifics.

Comment: welcome.  just a guess ... since often with bibtex the `.bib` file is essentially a cumulative database, the convention is to include in a document's reference list only the works that are actually cited.  if you want *everything* in the file to be included, add the command `\nocite{*}`.  (as @marmot says, though, if this is not an ordinary bibtex bibliography, the situation may be different.)

Comment: Oh wow, thank you. I hadn't known there is such a welcoming stackexchange community..!

Comment: What I meant to ask is while I intended to print all the references that I read and was inspired by, tex file wouldn't compile and print the reference list that I didn't include in the working paper as `\cite{name of the reference}`. Exactly as barbara guessed. I will try your suggestion. Appreciation once again.

Comment: What you are seeing is normal behaviour. If you use a `.bib` file only entries that are `\cite`d go to the bibliography at the end. You can add specific sources you don't want to cite explicitly to the bibliography with `\nocite{sigfridsson}`. With `\nocite{*}` you add all entries of your `.bib` file to the bibliography. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128/35864

Comment: While we could work out with a bit of guessing what your question was about and the exact details of your document did not really matter for the specifics of the question (most bibliography systems support `\nocite` in one way or other - except manual bibliographies, but they don't use `.bib` files and always list all entries in the bibliography, so that could not have been it), this is certainly not always the case. It is therefore a good habit to post an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) with your question. ...

Comment: ... In this case the MWE would have told us what method you use to create your bibliography (`amsrefs`, standard BibTeX with `natbib`, `cite`, `jurabib`, or `biblatex` ...), the style you use and how you currently cite your sources. An MWE makes sure that we are all talking about the same thing, it also helps people to understand your question more quickly and to get started answering at once.