# Generating a citations list with LaTeXiT?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, latexit

Is there a way to generate a citations list in LaTeXiT?

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17128/using-bibtex-to-make-a-list-of-references-without-having-citations-in-the-body-of) provides a method (in a normal LaTeX environment) for adding citations to the citation list without having them cited in the document. Then, in LaTeXiT's `Preferences > Advanced > Additional Files`, I've added the bibliography file. However, this produces no references list. If I use the ordinary `\cite` command, I see that `[CITATION_KEY_NAME]` is output by LaTeXiT. It seems that LaTeXiT will not run `biber` (or equivalent). Is there a better way to get LaTeXiT generate the desired citations list? Thank you!

Comment: This seems to far beyond the scope of LaTeXiT which is meant to be an equation editor.  I don't think it offers you a way to run BibTeX/Biber.  It might be a better idea to prepare your whole document using LaTeX if you want to take advantage of its reference formatting.

Comment: I partially take back what I said above.  It might actually be possible to run BibTeX/Biber from LaTeXiT.  You can orient yourself on this example with feynmp: http://osksn2.hep.sci.osaka-u.ac.jp/~taku/osx/feynmp_latexit.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a pre-processing script in the preferences of LaTeXiT under `Typesetting > Additional scripts`. Check the box to enable `Pre-processing`, then add the following (replacing the compiler and bibliography tool being used if not LuaLatex and Biber, respectively):

```
lualatex $INPUTTEXFILE
biber $INPUTFILE
lualatex $INPUTTEXFILE
```

This will lead to longer LaTeXiT compile times, so under that same preference tab, it may make sense to add a separate configuration for this, so the default can still be used for regular LaTeXiT usage.

This answer assumes the bibliography file was added to LaTeXiT as described in the question.

I was looking to add individual citations to (non-Beamer) slides. For others who would like to do the same thing, here are a few other pointers (assuming `biblatex`). In the preamble, use `\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}` to remove the citation number. And for the main LaTeXiT code use:

```
\nocite{CITATION_KEY}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
```

This will give the citation by itself in LaTeXiT.

Credit to @HenriMenke in the comments for the pointer to the solution.