# Beamer only includes part of the references in bibtex file

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I have a file call `mybib.bib`. In my `beamer` presentation, I do this:

```
   \usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric]{biblatex}
   \addbibresource{mybib.bib}
```

Then in the frame that I want the references to appear, I did:

```
\begin{frame}
   \printbibliography
 \end{frame}
```

This only prints out like 2 references in `mybib.bib`.  I have more than 20 references.  How do I get beamer to print out all references?

Comment: By default `biblatex` will only print references that you actually `\cite`d inthe document in the bibliography. If you want to see entries from the `.bib` file in the bibliography that were not cited, use `\nocite{<key>}` or `\nocite{*}` to add all entries. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128/35864

Comment: Do you mean to add \nocite{*} in the frame that I want to have all references? So between the \begin{frame} and \end{frame}, add \nocite{*}, then do \printbibliography?

Comment: You can use `\nocite{*}` or `\nocite{<entrykey>}` anywhere in your document after you have loaded `biblatex`. I think it makes sense to either issue it in the preamble close to `\addbibresource` or in the document close to `\printbibliography`, but that's just personal preference.

Comment: Thanks.  It turns out adding \nocite{*} in preamble after loaded Bibtex works.

Comment: Very good. Would you agree that your question is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128/35864?

Comment: Yes I agree it is a duplicate

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Voted to close as a duplicate.