# Bibliography shows only article_key and book_key but not other references on The Legrand Orange Book template

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

To whom it may concern,

I compiled the Legrand Orange Book template via TeXmaker successfully. I did not modify anything on the template. However, when I am running Biber (2.13) to build bibliography section by inputting

```
@book{book_key,
    address = {City},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    author = {Smith, John},
    title = {Book title},
    year = {2012},
    volume = {3},
    series = {5},
    edition = {1},
    pages = {123--200},
    month = {1}
}

@book{book_key1,
    address = {City},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    author = {Smith, John},
    title = {Book title},
    year = {2012},
    volume = {3},
    series = {5},
    edition = {1},
    pages = {123--200},
    month = {1}
}

@article{article_key,
    address = {City},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    author = {Smith, James},
    title = {Article title},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {15},
    number = {6},
    pages = {1--8},
    month = {3}
}

@article{article_key1,
    address = {City},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    author = {Smith, James},
    title = {Article title},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {14},
    number = {6},
    pages = {1--8},
    month = {3}
}
```

to `bibliography.bib` file. Unfortunately, only references with `book_key` and `article_key` appear on the pdf but not the rest. I attempts to find the solutions myself such as deleting `main.bcf` and `main.bbl` before recompile but still cannot solve it now. Could anyone suggest me on this?

Comment: Does the `.blg` file tell you anything useful? Did you cite the other entries that don't appear? (Biber - and also BibTeX - will only add entries that were actually `\cite`d in the document to the bibliography. If you want to add an entry to the bibliography without citing it explicitly, you can use `\nocite{<key>}`, with `\nocite{*}` you can add all available entries to the bibliography at once. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128/35864 and https://texfaq.org/FAQ-nocitestar)

Comment: Thank you so much. I solved the problem. I am very appreciated your help