# \printbibliography doesn't work with Biblatex and Texmaker

Tags: biblatex

I'm using for the first time biblatex

The main file is similar to the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}


\usepackage[space]{grffile}%para os directórios com espaços não darem problemas

\usepackage{float}% para os floats, aka imagens e tabelas, ficarem onde queremos. Usar [H] em vez de [h]
\graphicspath{ {Imagens/} }
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\floatname{algorithm}{Algorithm}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{
->, % makes the edges directed
>=stealth', % makes the arrow heads bold
node distance=3cm, % specifies the minimum distance between two nodes. Change if necessary.
every state/.style={thick, fill=gray!10}, % sets the properties for each 'state' node
initial text=$ $, % sets the text that appears on the start arrow
}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{property}{Property} [subsection]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition} [subsection]

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=red,
    filecolor=red,      
    urlcolor=red,
    pdfnewwindow %para o comando href não fechar a apresentação ao abrir novos pdf's
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{xcolor}%Comment out before printing
%\pagecolor[rgb]{0,0,0}%Comment out before printing
%\color[rgb]{1,1,1}%Comment out before printing
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\input{titlepage}

\chapter*{Abstract}
\input{Abstract/Abstract}

\chapter*{Dedication}
To  

\chapter*{Declaration}
I declare that..

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
I ack

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Towards a First Chapter}


\chapter{Dealing with a Second Chapter}


\printbibliography

\cite{Stuart10} is a testing crucible

\end{document}
```

The .bib file has the following text:

```
@article{<Stuart10>,
    author        = {Stuart},
    title         = {Some Very Difficult Problems},
    journaltitle  = {Numerology},
    year          = {1820},
    volume        = {1},
    pages         = {451-559}
}
```

However, when I compile, every thing appears fine except for the Bibliography section which never appears... There's no error warning, and everything is compiled smoothly.

Comment: Did you run `biber <file>` and then again `pdflatex <file>`??

Comment: @user187802 I'm sorry... I don't get what you mean by running a biber<file>

Comment: You have `\cite{Stuart10}` in your `.tex` file, but `@article{<Stuart10>,` in your `.bib` file. Remove the `<` and `>` in the `.bib` file and compile again.

Comment: @moewe I've done that, but same problem...

Comment: `biber` is an external program and should be run automaticly by texmaker. But in sone cases it doesn't. Look into the menu where the programs can be startet and choose `biber`

Comment: Thanks to @user187802 and moewe. I think I got it. However, now only the references which are cited show up. If I have some references in the .bib file which are not cited in the main text, they do not show up in the pdf...

Comment: `\nocite{*}` for all

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 for explanations what Biber does, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help on getting your editor to run Biber, and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128/35864 for `\nocite`

Comment: If one of the linked answers addresses your question, please let us know so we can close this as a duplicate. If you think none of the linked questions comes close, please write an answer by yourself and accept it. That way this question won't remain open/unanswered.

Comment: For future reference: https://www.xm1math.net/doculatex/biblatex.html

Comment: @moewe in my comment above, there's a link to the page that helped me. It's in French, but the snapshots may help even if you don't know french.