# Biblatex only printed the reference lists which cited in main body

Tags: biblatex

I am new to LaTeX, and I am using `biblatex` for my project.

I have created a `Reference.bib` file which listed all the references regardless of whether they have been cited in the main body or not.
And I want the whole references list printed by the command `\printbibliography`. 
Nevertheless, after compiling, it only printed the reference lists which were cited earlier in the main body. I am wondering is there anyone who might give me some advice? Any help is highly appreciated.

The preamble I used in my project is as below:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
            style=numeric,   
            isbn=false,               
            pagetracker=true,        
            maxbibnames=50,           
            maxcitenames=3,           
            autocite=inline,        
            block=space,               
            backref=true,              
            backrefstyle=three+,     
            date=short]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Reference.bib}
```

Comment: `\nocite{*}` prints all

Comment: Thanks @Johannes_B, I saw that command, but in other questions others seemed use that for "only print references cited". It works perfect! Thanks so much!!

Comment: Please don't answer questions in and edit to the question. Usually  you  would just write an answer instead. Since this question is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17128 you don't need to write an answer, it can simply be linked to that question.