# Don't showing bibliography and citations ,Please help

Tags: bibliographies, citing, multiple-citations

**I am using XeLaTex engine , it compiles but neither citations nor bibliography  are  showing in output document**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol,caption}
% Figure 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\newenvironment{Figure}
 {\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}}
 {\endminipage\par\medskip}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic]{Simplified Arabic} % Replace 'Simplified Arabic' with a font from your system
%--------------------------------
%in the preamble
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
%--------------------------------
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
This is my abstract
\end{abstract}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Introduction}
Introductin ......

    \begin{Arabic}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|l|}
    \hline
    Central Kurdish (Soraní - modified Arabic) & \#  \\ \hline
        ئا   ـا   ا                                & 1.  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{Arabic}
\end{multicols}
 \begin{multicols}{2}
\section{PHASES OF DESIGNING MRWL}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
\end{multicols}
 \begin{multicols}{2}
    
    
      Cite here \cite{einstein}.   \cite{einstein}.
      \printbibliography
    
   
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

=====================

## [image: Warnings]

```
This is sample.bib

@article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Please [edit] your post to include the additional information that you posted below.  Also, could you please add a sentence or two that explains what your problem is?  A title is not normally sufficient, and yours is also difficult to understand.

Comment: I don't have the font `Simplified Arabic` so I used `NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf`, but other than that the example compiles for me and produces a bibliography with one entry (`einstein`). (This is expected since LaTeX only lists references that were `\cite`d or `\nocite`d in the bibliography, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128/35864.) Did you run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX on your document? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.

Comment: Note also that the mapping `\DeclareLanguageMapping{UKenglish}{british}` is not required (or at least it should not be required; I would consider it a bug if you need it) and that the example `.bib` entries are not of the highest quality when used with `biblatex`. The `doi` field should only contain the DOI and not the full URL: `doi = {10.1002/andp.19053221004},` would be better. There should be no need to escape special characters in the `url` field, so `url = {http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html},` would be correct.

Comment: I have modified question according your instruction , Thank you

Comment: Did you compile your document with XeLaTeX, Biber, XeLaTeX, XeLaTeX? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains why you need to run Biber (the answer mainly mentions BibTeX, but the principle is the same for BibTeX and Biber). https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 explains how you can configure your editor to run Biber for you.