# Why does only one bibliography show up?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm trying to cite several websites and a book but for some reason the only bibliography that shows up is the one for the book. This is what is inside my bib file (called refs.bib)

```
@article{ochsenbein2000vizier,
  title={The VizieR database of astronomical catalogues},
  author={Ochsenbein, Fran{\c{c}}ois and Bauer, Patricia and Marcout, James},
  journal={Astronomy and Astrophysics Supplement Series},
  volume={143},
  number={1},
  pages={23--32},
  year={2000},
  publisher={EDP Sciences}
}

@book{book:Herschel,
author = {J.F.W. Herschel},
year = {1847},
title = {Cape of Good Hope Astronomical observations 1834-1838},
publisher = {Cape Results},
}

@misc{website:stelladoppie,
    title     = {WDS 09545-8025 HJ 4281},
    url       = {\url{https://www.stelledoppie.it/index2.phpiddoppia=45333}},
}

@misc{lco:obs,
    author    = {Sariah Phipps},
    url       = {\url{https://lco.global/observatory/0.4m}},
    year      = {2020},
}

@misc{website:gaia,
    author    = {European Space Agency},
    url       = {\url{https://www.esa.int/ Our_Activities/Space_Science/Gaia_overview}},
    year      = {2016},
    title     = {Gaia Overview},
}
```

and this is how I am trying to reference them in my main file

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{refs}
```

Any guidance on what I'm doing wrong is very appreciated!

Comment: you need to `\cite` the entries in your document (and re-run bibtex) to make a bibliography.

Comment: Welcome to tex,sx.  If you want something listed only in the bibliography, without a `\cite` in the text, "force" it with `\nocite{<id>}`, or if you want everything in the `.bib` file included, `\nocite{*}`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128/35864