# Empty bibliography problem

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to add a reference list to my latex file but the bibliography list is empty when I compile it even though there are entries in my reference list.

The packages I use are:

```
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
```

Then sample.bib looks like this:

```
  @article{FL2011,
    author = {Fredlund, D. G. and Sheng, D. and Zhao, J.},
    title = {Estimation of soil suction from the soil-water characteristic curve},
    journal = {Canadian Geotechnical Journal},
    volume = {48},
    number = {2},
    pages = {186-198},
    year = {2011},
}

    @article{SZF09,
        author = {Sheng, D. and Zhao, A. and Fredlund, D. G.},
        title = {Shear Strength Criteria for Unsaturated Soils Shear Strength Criteria for Unsaturated Soils},
        journal = {Geotechnical and Geological Engineering},
        volume = {29},
        pages = {145-159},
        year = {2011},
    }
```

And in my report I want to get my reference list like this:

```
\newpage
\printbibliography
```

But when I compile I get no reference list and two warnings:

> Empty bibliography on input line 195.
>
> BibTeX The file 'output.bcf' does not contain any citations!

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: You need to cite a citation, either with `\cite{FL2011}` or `\nocite{FL2011}` or `\nocite{*}`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128/35864

Comment: Any news here? Did you manage to solve your problem. As Ulrike says, the most likely cause of the symptoms you are seeing is that you have neither `\cite`d nor `\nocite`d any sources in your document. `biblatex` will only show sources that you `\cite`d or `\nocite`d in the bibliography.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to type up a quick answer here or is this a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128/35864?