# How to include a bib file into my latex file?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, compiling, tex-core

What is wrong with my code? It doesn't compile!

I use Zotero to gather my references. I exported the references from Zotero as biblatex file, and I used this code and It doesn't compile!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}

\begin{document}


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

It tells me: "empty bibliography", and the bib file is not empty.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you heard about an external program called `biber`?

Comment: You have no citations so the bibliography would be empty (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128/106162) even after running `biber` which is necessary. The bib file is just a source for references, they're not automatically added to any bibliography, you most likely want `\nocite{*}` for that (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17132/106162)

Answer (score 3):

Welcome, you could use biber:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}   %your bibliography name 
\usepackage{csquotes}


\begin{document}

Test  test \cite{ref-key}

\printbibliography                  %Your bibliography

\end{document}
```

then run

```
pdflatex <your file>
biber    <your file>
pdflatex <your file>
pdflatex <your file>
```

on you folder