# Print whole bibliography to PDF

Tags: bibliographies, citing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate a complete bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6885/generate-a-complete-bibliography)
>   [Using BibTeX to make a list of references without having citations in the body of the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17128/using-bibtex-to-make-a-list-of-references-without-having-citations-in-the-body-o)

I got the task to show my whole bibliography to my teacher and I'm not sure she is happy to handle a `.bib` file. So I try to print them into a PDF. At first I tried a normal LaTeX bibliography, but the problem is, that LaTeX wants to be smart about it and only uses the `.bib` entries that are actually used in citations. Do I have other options to get the whole library printed? Citing all entries from my library will be quite a hassle, because there are a lot.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
\nocite{*}
```

to reference all the content of your `.bib` file without actually citing every single reference.