# Display every bibtex file entry when calling \bibliography{literatur}

Tags: beamer, bibtex

I'm using `bibtex` in combination with the LaTeX `beamer` class and have one `literature.bib` file in the same directory. In my presentation I cite several entries of `literature.bib` but I want each and every entry displayed afterwards when calling `\bibliography{literatur}` (independently from possible `\cite{}` commands). Is that possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Add `\nocite{*}` somewhere in your document, for instance just after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Duplicate of [Generate a complete bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6885) or [Using BibTeX to make a list of references without having citations in the body of the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128)