# Issue with tapuscrit style and bibtex

Tags: bibtex, markdown, csquotes, quotation

I'm writing my PhD thesis in markdown and using Bibtex with Zotero. I'm having some issues with the quotation style I'm using, which is a slightly modified version of the tapuscrit, when converting my document to PDF. First, when I quote an article, there is a space between the quotation marks and the title but the length of this space is not equal between the former and the latter.
Secondly, when I quote the same reference successively, the ibid. mention appears but the name of the author(s) is quoted again, when it shouldn't be the case.
Thirdly, when quoting again a reference, only the initials of the author's first name appear, but there is a space missing between the author's two first names, if any.
Finally, I have an issue with the quotation marks when there is a need to put them in a title of an article with French quotation marks. Two closing quotation marks appear, even at the beginning of the quoted text.
I attach four screenshots that illustrate the issues:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is a MWE in markdown:

```
---
csl: le-tapuscrit-note-modified.csl
bibliography:[bibtex file]
link-citations: yes
lang: fr-FR
output: pdf_document
geometry: "margin=2.5cm"
fontfamily: libertine
fontsize: 12pt
documentclass: report
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  - \usepackage{csquotes}
  - \usepackage[bottom,hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
  - \setlength{\skip\footins}{1.2pc plus 5pt minus 2pt}
  - \setlength{\footnotemargin}{0pt}
  - \renewcommand\footnotelayout{\hskip5pt}
---

[^1] [^2] [^3] [^4]

[^1]: @tarrowStrategyPairedComparison2010

[^2]: @margalitNationalSelfDetermination1990

[^3]: @hobsbawmInventionTradition2010

[^4]: @bertrandHistoireGlobaleHistoires2013
```

Bibliography entries:

```
@incollection{bertrandHistoireGlobaleHistoires2013,
  title = {{Histoire globale, histoires connect\'ees : un "tournant" historiographique ?}},
  booktitle = {{Le "tournant global" des sciences sociales}},
  author = {Bertrand, Romain},
  editor = {Caill{\'e}, Alain and Dufoix, St{\'e}phane},
  year = {2013},
  pages = {44--66},
  publisher = {{La D\'ecouverte}},
  address = {{Paris}},
  langid = {french},
}

@book{hobsbawmInventionTradition2010,
  title = {The {{Invention}} of {{Tradition}}},
  editor = {Hobsbawm, Eric J. and Ranger, Terence O.},
  year = {2010},
  edition = {Second},
  publisher = {{Cambridge University Press}},
  address = {{Cambridge}},
}

@article{margalitNationalSelfDetermination1990,
  title = {National {{Self}}-{{Determination}}},
  author = {Margalit, Avishai and Raz, Joseph},
  year = {1990},
  journal = {Journal of Philosophy},
  volume = {87},
  number = {9},
  pages = {439--461},
}

@article{tarrowStrategyPairedComparison2010,
  title = {The Strategy of Paired Comparison: Toward a Theory of Practice},
  shorttitle = {The Strategy of Paired Comparison},
  author = {Tarrow, Sidney},
  year = {2010},
  month = feb,
  journal = {Comparative Political Studies},
  volume = {43},
  number = {2},
  pages = {230--259},
  issn = {0010-4140, 1552-3829},
  doi = {10.1177/0010414009350044},
  langid = {english},
}
```

And the CSL code in case it is useful:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<style xmlns="http://purl.org/net/xbiblio/csl" class="note" default-locale="fr-FR" version="1.0" page-range-format="expanded">
  <!-- This style was edited with the Visual CSL Editor (https://editor.citationstyles.org/visualEditor/) -->
  <info>
    <title>Le tapuscrit (École des hautes études en sciences sociales) (note, Français)</title>
    <title-short>Tapuscrit-EHESS</title-short>
    <id>http://www.zotero.org/styles/le-tapuscrit-ecole-des-hautes-etudes-en-sciences-sociales</id>
    <link href="http://www.zotero.org/styles/le-tapuscrit-ecole-des-hautes-etudes-en-sciences-sociales" rel="self"/>
    <link href="http://www.editions.ehess.fr/ouvrages/ouvrage/le-tapuscrit/" rel="documentation"/>
    <author>
      <name>Franziska Heimburger</name>
      <email>zotero@franziska.fr</email>
    </author>
    <category citation-format="note"/>
    <category field="social_science"/>
    <category field="generic-base"/>
    <updated>2021-09-08T15:34:46+00:00</updated>
    <rights license="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 License</rights>
  </info>
  <locale xml:lang="fr">
    <terms>
      <term name="ordinal-01">ère</term>
      <term name="ordinal-02">e</term>
      <term name="ordinal-03">e</term>
      <term name="ordinal-04">e</term>
      <term name="cited">op. cit.</term>
      <term name="page" form="short">p.</term>
      <term name="editor" form="short">
        <term name="issue" form="short">n°</term>
        <single>ed.</single>
        <multiple>eds.</multiple>
      </term>
      <term name="in">dans</term>
    </terms>
  </locale>
  <macro name="author">
    <names variable="author">
      <name form="long" and="text" delimiter-precedes-last="never" sort-separator=" "/>
      <label form="short" prefix=" (" suffix=".)"/>
      <substitute>
        <names variable="editor"/>
        <names variable="translator"/>
        <text macro="title"/>
      </substitute>
    </names>
  </macro>
  <macro name="author-bib">
    <names variable="author">
      <name name-as-sort-order="all" form="long" and="text" delimiter-precedes-last="never" sort-separator=" ">
        <name-part name="family" font-variant="small-caps"/>
      </name>
      <label form="short" prefix=" (" suffix=".)"/>
      <substitute>
        <names variable="editor"/>
        <names variable="translator"/>
        <text macro="title"/>
      </substitute>
    </names>
  </macro>
  <macro name="author-ibid">
    <names variable="author">
      <name and="text" initialize="true" initialize-with="." delimiter-precedes-last="never" sort-separator=" " font-style="normal"/>
      <label form="short" prefix=" (" suffix=".)"/>
      <substitute>
        <names variable="editor"/>
        <names variable="translator"/>
        <text macro="title"/>
      </substitute>
    </names>
  </macro>
  <macro name="editor">
    <names variable="editor">
      <name form="long" and="text" delimiter-precedes-last="never" sort-separator=" "/>
      <label form="short" prefix=" (" suffix=".)"/>
    </names>
  </macro>
  <macro name="translator">
    <names variable="translator">
      <name form="long" and="text" delimiter-precedes-last="never" sort-separator=" " prefix=" traduit par "/>
    </names>
  </macro>
  <macro name="title">
    <choose>
      <if type="bill book graphic legal_case motion_picture report song" match="any">
        <text variable="title" text-case="capitalize-first" font-style="italic"/>
      </if>
      <else-if type="article-journal article-newspaper article-magazine" match="any">
        <group delimiter=", ">
          <text variable="title" text-case="capitalize-first" strip-periods="true" quotes="true"/>
          <text variable="container-title" font-style="italic"/>
        </group>
      </else-if>
      <else-if type="thesis" match="any">
        <group delimiter="">
          <text variable="title" text-case="capitalize-first" font-style="italic" suffix=","/>
          <text variable="genre" suffix=", " prefix=" "/>
          <text variable="publisher"/>
        </group>
      </else-if>
      <else-if type="manuscript" match="any">
        <group delimiter=",">
          <text variable="title" text-case="capitalize-first" font-style="italic"/>
          <text variable="genre" prefix=" [" suffix="]"/>
        </group>
      </else-if>
      <else-if type="chapter entry-dictionary entry-encyclopedia" match="any">
        <group delimiter="">
          <text variable="title" text-case="capitalize-first" strip-periods="false" quotes="true"/>
          <text value="dans" suffix=" " prefix=" "/>
          <text macro="editor" suffix=", "/>
          <text variable="container-title" text-case="capitalize-first" font-style="italic"/>
        </group>
      </else-if>
      <else-if type="webpage post-weblog" match="any">
        <group delimiter="">
          <text variable="title" text-case="capitalize-first" font-style="italic" suffix=", "/>
          <text variable="URL"/>
          <group prefix=", ">
            <date variable="issued">
              <date-part name="day" suffix=" "/>
              <date-part name="month" suffix=" "/>
              <date-part name="year"/>
            </date>
          </group>
        </group>
      </else-if>
      <else>
        <text variable="title" quotes="true"/>
      </else>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <macro name="pub-place">
    <choose>
      <if type="bill book chapter entry-dictionary entry-encyclopedia thesis graphic legal_case manuscript motion_picture paper-conference report song" match="any">
        <choose>
          <if variable="publisher-place" match="any">
            <text variable="publisher-place"/>
          </if>
          <else>
            <text value="s.l."/>
          </else>
        </choose>
      </if>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <macro name="publisher">
    <choose>
      <if type="bill book chapter entry-dictionary entry-encyclopedia graphic legal_case motion_picture paper-conference report song" match="any">
        <text variable="publisher"/>
      </if>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <macro name="yearpage">
    <choose>
      <if type="bill book graphic legal_case motion_picture paper-conference manuscript report song thesis" match="any">
        <group delimiter=", ">
          <group delimiter=" ">
            <date variable="issued" form="numeric" date-parts="year"/>
            <date variable="original-date" form="numeric" date-parts="year" prefix="[" suffix="]"/>
          </group>
          <group>
            <text term="volume" form="short" suffix="."/>
            <text variable="number-of-volumes" prefix=". " suffix="/"/>
            <text variable="volume"/>
          </group>
          <choose>
            <if variable="locator" match="any">
              <group delimiter=" ">
                <label variable="locator" form="short"/>
                <text variable="locator"/>
              </group>
            </if>
            <else-if variable="locator" match="none"/>
          </choose>
        </group>
      </if>
      <else-if type="chapter entry-dictionary entry-encyclopedia" match="any">
        <group delimiter=" ">
          <group delimiter=" ">
            <date variable="issued" form="numeric" date-parts="year"/>
            <date variable="original-date" form="numeric" date-parts="year" prefix="[" suffix="]"/>
          </group>
          <group>
            <text term="volume" form="short" suffix="."/>
            <text variable="number-of-volumes" prefix=". " suffix="/"/>
            <text variable="volume" suffix=","/>
          </group>
          <choose>
            <if variable="locator" match="any">
              <group delimiter=" ">
                <label variable="locator" form="short"/>
                <text variable="locator"/>
              </group>
            </if>
          </choose>
        </group>
      </else-if>
      <else-if type="article-journal" match="any"/>
      <else-if type="article-newspaper article-magazine" match="any">
        <date variable="issued">
          <date-part name="day" suffix=" "/>
          <date-part name="month" form="short" suffix=" "/>
          <date-part name="year"/>
        </date>
        <group delimiter=" " font-style="normal">
          <label variable="page" form="short"/>
          <text variable="page"/>
        </group>
        <group delimiter=" " font-style="normal">
          <choose>
            <if variable="locator" match="any">
              <group delimiter=" ">
                <label variable="locator" form="short"/>
                <text variable="locator"/>
              </group>
            </if>
            <else-if variable="locator" match="none">
              <label variable="page" form="short"/>
            </else-if>
          </choose>
        </group>
      </else-if>
      <else-if type="webpage post-weblog" match="any">
        <group delimiter=" " prefix="(" suffix=")">
          <text value="consulté le"/>
          <date variable="accessed" form="text">
            <date-part name="day"/>
            <date-part name="month"/>
            <date-part name="year"/>
          </date>
        </group>
      </else-if>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <macro name="yearpage-bib">
    <choose>
      <if type="bill book graphic legal_case motion_picture paper-conference report song thesis" match="any">
        <group delimiter=", ">
          <group delimiter=", ">
            <group delimiter=" ">
              <date variable="issued" form="numeric" date-parts="year"/>
              <date variable="original-date" form="numeric" date-parts="year" prefix="[" suffix="]"/>
            </group>
            <group>
              <text term="volume" form="short" suffix="."/>
              <text variable="number-of-volumes" prefix=". " suffix="/"/>
              <text variable="volume"/>
            </group>
          </group>
          <group>
            <label variable="locator" form="short"/>
            <text variable="locator"/>
          </group>
        </group>
      </if>
      <else-if type="chapter entry-dictionary entry-encyclopedia" match="any">
        <group delimiter=", ">
          <group delimiter=" ">
            <date variable="issued" form="numeric" date-parts="year"/>
            <date variable="original-date" form="numeric" date-parts="year" prefix="[" suffix="]"/>
          </group>
          <group>
            <text term="volume" form="short" suffix="."/>
            <text variable="number-of-volumes" prefix=". " suffix="/"/>
            <text variable="volume"/>
          </group>
          <group>
            <label variable="page" form="short"/>
            <text variable="page" prefix=" "/>
          </group>
        </group>
      </else-if>
      <else-if type="article-journal" match="any">
        <group delimiter=" ">
          <label variable="page" form="short"/>
          <text variable="page"/>
        </group>
      </else-if>
      <else-if type="article-newspaper article-magazine" match="any">
        <group delimiter=" ">
          <date variable="issued">
            <date-part name="day" suffix=" "/>
            <date-part name="month" form="short" suffix=" "/>
            <date-part name="year"/>
          </date>
          <label variable="page" form="short"/>
          <text variable="page"/>
        </group>
      </else-if>
      <else-if type="manuscript">
        <group delimiter="" font-style="normal">
          <choose>
            <if variable="issued">
              <date variable="issued">
                <date-part name="day" suffix=" "/>
                <date-part name="month" suffix=" "/>
                <date-part name="year"/>
              </date>
            </if>
            <else>
              <text value="s. d."/>
            </else>
          </choose>
        </group>
      </else-if>
      <else-if type="webpage post-weblog" match="any">
        <group delimiter=" ">
          <text value="consulté le" suffix=" " prefix=" "/>
          <date variable="accessed" form="text">
            <date-part name="day"/>
            <date-part name="month"/>
            <date-part name="year"/>
          </date>
        </group>
      </else-if>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <macro name="edition">
    <choose>
      <if type="bill book graphic legal_case motion_picture report song chapter paper-conference" match="any">
        <choose>
          <if is-numeric="edition">
            <group delimiter=" ">
              <number variable="edition" form="ordinal"/>
              <text term="edition" form="short"/>
            </group>
          </if>
          <else>
            <text variable="edition" text-case="capitalize-first" suffix="."/>
          </else>
        </choose>
      </if>
      <else-if type="article-journal article-magazine" match="any">
        <group delimiter="">
          <choose>
            <if variable="issued">
              <date variable="issued">
                <date-part name="day" suffix=" "/>
                <date-part name="month" suffix=" "/>
                <date-part name="year"/>
              </date>
              <text macro="volume" prefix=", "/>
            </if>
            <else>
              <text macro="volume" text-case="capitalize-first"/>
            </else>
          </choose>
        </group>
      </else-if>
    </choose>
    <text macro="issue" prefix=", "/>
  </macro>
  <macro name="volume">
    <choose>
      <if is-numeric="volume">
        <text term="volume" form="short" suffix=". "/>
        <text variable="volume"/>
      </if>
      <else>
        <text variable="volume"/>
      </else>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <macro name="issue">
    <choose>
      <if is-numeric="issue">
        <text term="issue" form="short" suffix=" "/>
        <text variable="issue"/>
      </if>
      <else>
        <text variable="issue"/>
      </else>
    </choose>
  </macro>
  <macro name="collection">
    <text variable="collection-title" quotes="true" prefix=" (coll. " suffix=")"/>
  </macro>
  <citation et-al-min="4" et-al-use-first="1">
    <layout suffix="." delimiter=" ; ">
      <choose>
        <if position="ibid-with-locator">
          <group delimiter=", ">
            <text term="ibid" text-case="capitalize-first" font-style="italic" suffix="."/>
            <text variable="locator" prefix="p. "/>
          </group>
        </if>
        <else-if position="ibid">
          <text term="ibid" text-case="capitalize-first" font-style="italic"/>
        </else-if>
        <else-if position="subsequent">
          <group delimiter=", ">
            <text macro="author-ibid"/>
            <choose>
              <if type="bill book graphic legal_case motion_picture report song thesis manuscript" match="any">
                <text variable="title" form="short" font-style="italic"/>
                <text term="cited" font-style="italic" suffix="."/>
              </if>
              <else>
                <text variable="title" text-case="capitalize-first" form="short" quotes="true"/>
                <text value="art cit"/>
              </else>
            </choose>
            <text variable="locator" prefix="p. "/>
          </group>
        </else-if>
        <else>
          <choose>
            <if type="manuscript">
              <group delimiter=", ">
                <text variable="archive"/>
                <text variable="archive_location"/>
                <text variable="call-number"/>
                <text macro="title"/>
                <text macro="yearpage-bib"/>
              </group>
            </if>
            <else>
              <group delimiter=", ">
                <text macro="author"/>
                <text macro="title"/>
                <text macro="translator"/>
                <text macro="edition"/>
                <text macro="pub-place"/>
                <text macro="publisher"/>
                <text macro="yearpage"/>
              </group>
            </else>
          </choose>
        </else>
      </choose>
    </layout>
  </citation>
  <bibliography>
    <sort>
      <key macro="author" names-min="3" names-use-first="3"/>
      <key variable="issued" sort="descending"/>
    </sort>
    <layout suffix=".">
      <choose>
        <if type="manuscript">
          <group delimiter=", ">
            <text variable="archive"/>
            <text variable="archive_location"/>
            <text variable="call-number"/>
            <text macro="title"/>
            <text macro="yearpage-bib"/>
          </group>
        </if>
        <else>
          <group delimiter=", ">
            <text macro="author-bib"/>
            <text macro="title"/>
            <text macro="translator"/>
            <text macro="edition"/>
            <text macro="pub-place"/>
            <group delimiter=" ">
              <text macro="publisher"/>
              <text macro="collection"/>
            </group>
            <text macro="yearpage-bib"/>
          </group>
        </else>
      </choose>
    </layout>
  </bibliography>
</style>
```

Comment: Sorry for look like a bit picky, but this is not a MWE. At least it lacks of  a minimal .bib file and some after `bibliography:`. Preferably, use an already  available  [bibliography example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/549749/11604) for all of us,  so you don't have to post any .bib file, just modify the markdown accordingly and check that it works as posted without having to do anything.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I modified the MWE, I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Not enough: the screenshot is not  what your code produce, and moreover, repeating for instance the 3th cite, I obtain only  the editors in text with footnotes, the first  to the title plus "op.cit." and after that only "Ibid.",  so your problem is not clear. By the way, the problem of «» with spaces is due to the French setting (for instance, `lang: es` will not add spaces), so look at the  `babel-french` manual for the options. Note also that the field text of the  references must be valid LaTeX text, not markdown text, so `"tournament"` is not correct.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem of the French guillemets by using `babel` finally. However I don't how to solve the issue with the "ibid." as it must something from the YAML header or another command that produces this result. Concerning the quotes in the French guillemets, it must be an issue with the LaTeX text in the references as you mention. I generate them with Better BibTeX on Zotero, but there must be an issue concerning this specific sign. Do you maybe know how to solve it?

Comment: The `"` (single character) is not the way to  quoting  in LaTeX,   you must  use ` ` ' ' (four independent tildes)  or LaTeX comands for guillemots as  `\guilsinglleft{}` or directly «» and  ‹ ›  for a nested quote.