# Curated .bib example file

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Is there any `.bib` example file that is canonical in the community?

Ideally, such a file would

- Carry entries of all types (`book`, `inproceedings`, `misc`, etc.),
- Have entries with optional fields filled (for instance, an `article` entry with a `doi`, and one without),
- Use `string`s and `crossereference`s,
- Optionally offer more "modern" features of `BibLaTex` (such as `software` entries),
- Contain mostly freely accessible references,
- Be under an open source licence.

I found some files [such as this one](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/aguplus/sample.bib) on tug, but it is not satisfactory. As of now, I believe [`biblatex/biblatex-examples.bib`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/dev/bibtex/bib/biblatex/biblatex-examples.bib) is my best option, but maybe I did miss something?

Comment: No idea about if there are some better bib examples, only that there are many in TeX Live. A non updated list [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/549749/11604).

Comment: There is also `/bibtex/bib/base/xampl.bib` which contains many features, as a mix of real and made-up publications.

Comment: @Marijn https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/base/xampl.bib is indeed very good, thanks for pointing it out!